# using RazorEngine to iterate the model

Tags: .net, razor, razorengine

I'm using ElasticObject (http://elasticobject.codeplex.com/) to create the dynamic object which I feed the RazorEngine for template replacements.

The structure of the XML the ElasticObject is converting to a dynamic object is this:

```
<Book ChapterID="1123" ChapterName="Test Chapter" BookName="Sample Book" SectionName="Test Section">
    <StaffContact>
       <Contact FirstName="Jane" LastName="Doe" EmailAddress="janedoe@domain.com" />
       <Contact FirstName="John" LastName="Doe" EmailAddress="johndoe@domain.com" />
    </StaffContact>
</Book>
```

I am trying to figure out how to get to the Contact.UserFirstName, etc data

```
XmlNode BookNode = xmlLookupDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Book");
var elBook = XElement.Parse(BookNode.OuterXml).ToElastic();

//I build the Model object here - this is a simplified version of what I'm using
var razorViewModel = new { Book = elBook };
```

I can access the attributes of the Book node just fine by using:

```
@Model.Book.ChapterName
```

I'm just not sure how to iterate through the Model using RazorEngine.

I tried the following:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.StaffContact.Contact)
    {
        @item.model.UserFirstName @item.model.UserLastName at @item.model.UserEmailAddress 
    }
```

Any help you could give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, you described what have you tried, but what was the result? What was the output or were there any exceptions, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the ElasticObject documentation (which is not too much mainly some tests and some blog posts), try it like this:

```
@foreach (var contact in Model.Book.StaffContact[null])
{
    @contact.FirstName @contact.LastName at @contact.EmailAddress
}
```

Basically the property names should match the XML elements and attribute names however acessing collections a little bit tricky:

You can access the elements inside `StaffContact` with the help of a "null indexer" `Model.Book.StaffContact[null]` and now you can iterate over it.

In the `foreach` each item will be a `Contact` where you can access the FirstName attribute with the `FirstName` property and so on.

Comment: That did not work for me. `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>.this[int]' has some invalid arguments`